How to extract a text in between two patterns (potentially containing floating lookbehind) with only one invocation?
I'm trying to match any characters (except line break characters) in between xxx<1+ whitespaces>" and whitespace.
The format of the input string is the following:
xxx<1+ whitespaces>"yyy<1+ whitespaces>zzz"

I've tried to use the following PCRE:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | grep -Po '(?<=\xxx\s+").*?(?=\s)'
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

However, as we see, PCRE doesn't support floating lookbehind because it can cause major performance problems.
Here is the workaround:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | grep xxx | grep -Po '(?<=").*?(?=\s)'
yyy

Here we see that it works, however, grep is invoked two times, which may be considered suboptimal.
Is it possible to achieve the same result, but with only one grep invocation?
If no, then it possible to achieve the same result, but with only one <toolname> (perhaps awk) invocation?

"grep is invoked two times, which may be considered suboptimal" – I can see from this answer there is an elegant way with one grep, still in general there is no guarantee that one grep performs better than grep | grep. I can imagine in some cases clever piping may win. You were even willing to accept a different tool. Would you measure its performance and compare to 2xgrep? Or would you assume one tool is better than a pipe of two? For a small dataset it wouldn't matter anyway. My point is "optimization for optimization's sake" may be wrong.

Use reset operator: \K 
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | grep -Po 'xxx\s+"\K.*?(?=\s)'
yyy


As I see in \K the \K isn't named "reset operator". Is "reset operator" the official (i.e. established, settled) term for \K?

@pmor: I'm not sure there is an official name. Some people call it Match reset

grep is at tool to Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result, it's not a tool to edit text by selecting/discarding bits and pieces of the matching string, there are other perfectly good Unix tools to edit text with such as sed and awk.
Using GNU sed for -E for EREs and \s/\S shorthand for [[:space:]]/[^[:space:]]:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | sed -En 's/.*xxx\s+"(\S+).*/\1/p'
yyy

or any POSIX sed:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | sed -n 's/.*xxx[[:space:]]\{1,\}"\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
yyy

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and \s/\S:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | awk 'match($0,/xxx\s+"(\S+)/,a){print a[1]}'
yyy

or any POSIX awk:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | awk 'sub(/.*xxx[[:space:]]+"/,"") && match($0,/^[^[:space:]]+/){print substr($0,1,RLENGTH)}'
yyy

or, also with any POSIX awk:
$ echo 'xxx  "yyy zzz"' | awk 'match($0,/xxx[[:space:]]+"/) && match(substr($0,b=RSTART+RLENGTH),/^[^[:space:]]+/){print substr($0,b,RLENGTH)}'
yyy


The wording lookbehind assertion is not fixed length is confusing. Hence, the question: any idea why the wording is lookbehind assertion is not fixed length instead of lookbehind is not fixed length? Or perhaps it should be assertion: lookbehind is not fixed length?

No idea. I never use PCREs, just EREs and BREs which don't have look-anywheres, as PCREs just add unnecessary complexity to an already complicated domain ("Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.").

FYI: As I know, the (built-in?) grep, which is running in Cmake environment (i.e. cmake launches the underlying commands: compiler, etc.), doesn't support PCRE (option -P): grep: Unknown option 'P'. Hence, in case of Cmake I switched to ERE.

@pmor grep is never a builtin, it's always an external tool, but AFAIK only the GNU version of grep supports -P so for portability stick to the POSIX definition, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html, and if it's not easy to do with grep then just do it with awk.
